# Uploading downloaded json of dynamo db for a table

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have downloaded my remote dynamodb tables using this script.

https://github.com/bchew/dynamodump

I got the data inside my local folder now i want to upload this json to my local dynamo db. The command i am using is this.

```
sudo aws dynamodb put-item --table-name users --item file:///home/evbooth/Desktop/dynamo/table/dynamodump/dump/users/data/0001.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

And the format of the json is like this.

```
{
  "Count": 28,
  "Items": [
    {
      "userid": {
        "S": "chetankjain@gmail.com"
      },
      "password": {
        "S": "$2a$10$YoaOXLayZPnZOeWwd1zkpObs61pg/Qwjz78mKEFQs5Nla/iRoSsbm"
      },
      "role": {
        "S": "hr"
      }
    },
    {
      "userid": {
        "S": "call1test@gmail.com"
      },
      "password": {
        "S": "$2a$10$8NksGgORzDPgScWQ6Grs0Omk20ICUsA5xNPWWAhblrEWkA2tcFh1e"
      },
      "role": {
        "S": "candidate"
      }
    },
    {
      //
    }


  ],
  "ScannedCount": 28
}
```

But it is ending up as an error like this.

```
Parameter validation failed:
    Invalid type for parameter Item.Count, value: 28, type: <class 'int'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
    Invalid type for parameter Item.Items, value: [OrderedDict([('userid', OrderedDict([('S', 'chetankjain@gmail.com')])), ('password', OrderedDict([('S', '$2a$10$YoaOXLayZPnZOeWwd1zkpObs61pg/Qwjz78mKEFQs5Nla/iRoSsbm')])), ('role', OrderedDict([('S', 'hr')]))]),....................('role', OrderedDict([('S', 'candidate')]))])], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
Invalid type for parameter Item.ScannedCount, value: 28, type: <class 'int'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
```

How can i upload this query any idea?